# Decoding two 4K videos at the same time

Tags: java, android, video, android-mediacodec, grafika

I would like to decode and play two videos simultaneously. My code isn't very complicated, you can see decoder configuring part below. It's based on [google/grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika)'s MoviePlayer.

```
final String mime = format1.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
decoder1 = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
decoder1.configure(format1, mOutputSurface1, null, 0);
decoder1.start();

decoder2 = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
decoder2.configure(format2, mOutputSurface2, null, 0);
decoder2.start();
```

This worked great with videos up to 1080p, but when I tried to play 4K video, second decoder failed to configure with errors:

```
E/ACodec﹕ configureCodec multi window instance fail  appPid : 13182
E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -38
E/MediaCodec﹕ Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001001, internalError -38)
```

If I would leave only one decoder, it would work just fine even with 4K videos. I have found some discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602662/multiple-instances-of-mediacodec-used-as-video-encoder-in-android), but I'm not sure it's related to my problem. I can confirm this happens on Samsung Galaxy S6 and Samsung Galaxy Note 4. 
 Is there any way to make two decoders work with 4K videos?

Comment: Have you tried to use android.media.MediaMuxer to compress the videos before showing them?

Comment: @Fondesa No, I haven't. I'll give it a try if I won't fugure out something else. If I'm not wrong, compressing video may bring some significant lag to my app. But in the end - maybe I won't be able to avoid it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I would guess you're running up against bandwidth limitations in the decoder hardware.

Comment: From your question, it appears that the underlying decoder is capable of handling only one `4K` decode session. I presume this would translate into a capability of `4K 30 fps`. When we create the `decoder`, we can't provide a `fps` number. One experiment could be to create 2 sessions of `4K 15 fps`, but I doubt it will work as your error is in creation itself. The best bet could be to contact the device manufacturer as your requirement is very high 2 x 4K 30 fps decode is some serious amount of work

Comment: @Ganesh Out of couriosity I've tried to change framerate of the video, but it doesn't work either. Thanks for suggestions both of you. I think I'll just have to accept 1080p as the upper limit.

Comment: @KrzysztofKansy .. I think the underlying decoder is deciding based on the number of sessions and not the effective throughput.. so in this case, unless the decoder is not modified, I am not sure if there could be an alternative

Comment: @fadden Do you know if there's a way to query decoder bandwidth before attempting multiple decodes?

Comment: @PeterTran: there is not. According to http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#video the 'M' release is supposed to add a "hint for the max number of the supported concurrent codec instances". I don't know if that will help this specific situation or not.