# Need to encode and decode android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediacodec, renderscript

**MY GOALS**
1. Decode an MP4 Video.
2. Decode camera frames, edit with renderscript (apply effects)
3. Display the camera data inside an oval on top on the background video in Goal 1.
4. Encode the frames and use the MediaMuxer to save the video.

**MY PROBLEM**
I can successfully do goals 1-3 but I am stuck on goal 4. When I am using the second MediaCodec for encoding frames (1st MediaCodec is used in Goal 1), my whole app freezes and needs to be forced closed.

Can android actually handle two MediaCodecs simultaneously?
Can anyone offer any help on this please?
Thanks

Comment: It could be device-specific. Did you try on different devices?

Comment: Yes, two instances of MediaCodec can be used simultaneously. You need to figure out what your app is doing when it freezes up. Connect a debugger or DDMS and get stack traces.

Comment: Have you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602662/multiple-instances-of-mediacodec-used-as-video-encoder-in-android?rq=1?