# Working with Multiple MediaCodec & Muxer instances at a time

Tags: android-studio

I am using Media Codec with Media muxer for some Audio/Video operations, There are some other threads which is using MediaCodec & Muxer at the same time. Specifically, I am recording the webRTC sessions and doing some audio/video operation. WebRTC itself using MediaCodec & Muxer and parallelly I am trying to start another instance of these. In some devices, both threads are working fine but in some devices, MediaCodec has failed to instantiate. I saw this  [Multiple instances of MediaCodec used as video encoder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602662/multiple-instances-of-mediacodec-used-as-video-encoder-in-android). My question is,  By anyway can I make it work in all devices? any way to use the same MediaCodec & muxer object for different purposes at the same time. ?

Answer (score 0):

Its already mentioned [Marlon-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24605641/12659496).

> From my experience it completely depends on a device. And there are devices that are able to support only one instance of video encoder in one time.

One object of muxer with mediacodec can not be used by two or more threads that's not possible. If you want it to work in all devices then check for available modiacodec for muxer if it is available run it in parallel otherwise you have to chose sequential approach.